# SQLite Android rawQuery вытащить несколько полей по id

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, android-sqlite

Есть база данных myvocabulary, в ней поля _id, fname, secname.
Хочу с помощью rawquery или query доставать строки по id(по 4 значения). Допустим, (1,7,8,17). И передать их курсору.
Искал,искал, но ничего так и не сработало.
Пробовал что-то типа
`return mDB.rawQuery("select * from myvocabulary where _id = ?", columns);`
В columns
`String[] columns = {"1","2","3","4"};`

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ:

```
    String[] columns = {"1","2","9","6"};
    return mDB.query("mytable", null, "_id = ? or _id = ? or _id = ? or _id = ?", columns, null, null, null);
```